# ¿Que esta mal en esta linea de codigo PHP que me muestra los datos?

Tags: php, mysql, web

Estoy creado una aplicación básica con PHP de gestión de citas. Creé una archivo llamado `confirmarcitas.php`, el cual es encargado de mostrarme una vez se registre una cita a manera de confirmar los datos. El código HTML y PHP es el siguiente, lo estoy trabajando en Netbeans

```php
<?php  $fila =$result->fetch_object();
?>
<h2>Información de la Cita</h2>
<table class="table">
   <tr>
       <th colspan="2">Datos del Paciente</th>
            <tr>
                <td>Documento</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->PacIdentificacion;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre Completo del Paciente</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->PacNombres." ".$fila->PacApellidos;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Datos Medicos del Paciente</th> 
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>Documento</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->MedIdentificacion;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->MedNombres." ".$fila->MedApellidos;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Datos de la Cita</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Numero</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->CitNumero;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fecha</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->CitFecha;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hora</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->CitHora;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Numero de Consultorio</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->ConNumero;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre del Consultorio</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->ConNombre;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Estado</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->CitEstado;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Observaciones</td>
                <td><?php echo $fila->CitObservaciones;?></td>
            </tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```

El código en el modelo es el siguiente, el archivo se llama `GestionCitas`

```php
public function consultarCitaPorId($id){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $conexion->abrirConexion();
    $sql ="SELECT pacientes.*,consultorios.*,citas.* 
        FROM pacientes, medicos, consultorios,citas 
        WHERE citas.CitPaciente=pacientes.PacIdentificacion 
        AND citas.CitMedico = medicos.MedIdentificacion 
        AND citas.CitConsultorio = consultorios.ConNumero 
        AND citas.CitNumero=$id";
    $conexion->consulta($sql);
    $result = $conexion->obtenerResult();
    $conexion->cerrarConexion();
    return $result;
}
```

Y el código del controlador es el siguiente:

```php
<?php
class Controlador{
    public function verPagina($ruta){
        require_once $ruta;
    }
   
    public function agregarCita($doc,$med,$fec,$hor,$con){
        // Crear objeto de la clase Cita con los valores recibidos
        $cita = new Cita(null,$fec,$hor,$doc,$med,$con, "Solicitada", "Ninguna");
        // Agregar cita utilizando el objeto de la clase Gestion Citas
        $gestorCitas = new GestionCitas();
        //$gestorCitas->agregarCita($cita);
        $id =$gestorCitas->agregarCita($cita);
        $result =$gestorCitas->consultarCitaPorId($id);
        require_once 'Vista/confirmarCita.php';
    }
  
    public function consultarCitas($doc){
        $gestorCitas = new GestionCitas();
        $result = $gestorCitas->consultarCitasPorDocumento($doc);
        require_once 'Vista/consultarCitas.php';
    }
}
?>
```

Debería de mostrar los datos registrados, pero me muestra el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco si me pueden echar una mano.

Comment: Pareciera la consulta está incorrecta. Para verificarlo, en el archivo `GestionCitas.php` agrega un `echo $sql;`. Copia el resultado y pégalo directo en el editor de consultas de la base de datos (phpmyadmin, workbench, etc) a ver qué resultado trae. Acostúmbrate a usar [JOIN](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+uso+de+join) en las consultas, ya que las hace más claras y provee funcionalidad más potente. Finalmente, cuidado con las [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/80870).

Comment: Depura tu código. Para empezar, pon un `var_dump($result);` **justo debajo** de esta línea:`$result =$gestorCitas->consultarCitaPorId($id);`, en el método `agregarCita()`